# How can I make Skype chat UI dark?

Tags: skype

Are there any themes or tricks to make the Skype chat window black instead of white? I'm just tired of staring at a white screen while chatting on Skype. I figured there must be a way to make it dark, some Ubuntu expert might know!

Answer (score 1):

Skype provides no such customizations.  You can control something like brightness on your monitor or via software.  I would suggest trying any of these 3rd party applications to control the overall brightness of the screen.  It has an affect on Skype's illumination like any other application:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonls/redshift-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redshift
```

I have used this one and it's rather simple to execute and close.  This way it can be dynamically customized.  It should give you greater control and it doesn't require a theme change.